# Pass a value to bootstrap modal from a bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, html, flask, modal-dialog, jinja2

i am setting up a flask application (just started on flask this week, i am also inexperienced in html/javascript so don't shoot at me) and want to be able to delete data from database, but want to be able to have a modal showing up asking for the confirmation (because i think it looks nice and neat).

I have been trying for the past two days to make that modal confirmation work and haven't been able to achieve that. I have looked into similar question posted here already and wasn't able to make it work. So my attempt is a combination of what i found in those posts so far.

My table which is created using jinja(i think) looks like below and when a user clicks on the delete button, i want to show the confirmations modal and to be able to pass to the modal at least the "issuer.Id" value.

Would you be able to shed some light on what i do wrong or any advice how to approach it or any other idea to resolve this?
[image]

My code is here:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{%  block body %}

    <h2>Issuer Mappings</h2>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="add-issuer-mapping">Add mapping</a>
    <hr>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="allocationCodeInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for allocation codes.." title="Type in a allocation code">
    <hr>
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm ", id="IssuerMappingTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Allocation Code</th>
            <th>Issuer</th>
            <th>Backing</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Sector</th>
            <th width="150">Asset Class (Adj)</th>
            <th>PM (Adj)</th>
            <th>PM Initials</th>
            <th>Strategy (Adj)</th>
            <th>OffPiste</th>
            <th>Liquidity</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        {% for issuer in issuer_mappings %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="issuer-mappings/{{issuer.Id}}">{{issuer.AllocationCode}}</a></td>
                <td>{{ issuer.Issuer }}</td>
                <td>{{ issuer.Backing }}</td>
                <td>{{ issuer.Country }}</td>
                <td>{{ issuer.Region }}</td>
                <td>{{ issuer.Sector }}</td>
                <td>{{ issuer.AssetClass_ADJ }}</td>
                <td>{{ issuer.PM_ADJ }}</td>
                <td>{{ issuer.PM_Initials }}</td>
                <td>{{ issuer.Strategy_ADJ }}</td>
                <td>{{ issuer.OffPiste }}</td>
                <td>{{ issuer.Liquidity }}</td>
                <td><a href="issuer-mappings/edit-issuer-mapping/{{ issuer.Id }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm pull-right">Edit</a></td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#IssuerMappingDeleteModal" data-id="{{ issuer.Id }}">Delete</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <div id="IssuerMappingDeleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Delete Issuer Mapping?</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="issMapId">
                    <!-- display some how the id here-->
                    <p>The selected issuer mapping is about to be deleted.<br>Do you want to proceed?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <form method="POST"> <!-- to add the delete action later -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                        <input type="submit" value="Yes" class="btn btn-danger" >
                    </form>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
             var issuerMappingId = $(this).data('id');
             $(this).find('#issMapId').html($('<b> Issuer Mapping id: ' + issuerMappingId  + '</b>'))
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll want to submit your data using an Ajax request rather than a form submission on the page, which will cause the page to refresh/redirect. Ajax will allow you to send a request to the server without having to refresh the page every time. [jQuery.ajax() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

There are a few ways you could tackle this problem. I'd say that probably the easiest and best way would be to ditch the modal altogether define a wrapper function that sends the `DELETE` request to the remote server and replaces the modal functionality with a `confirm()` function (this returns true when confirmed).

For example:

```
function deleteIssuer(id){

  if (confirm("The selected issuer mapping is about to be deleted. Do you want to proceed?")){

    /*** Ajax request to server to delete goes here ***/

  } else {

    return;

  }
}
```

---

If you're absolutely sure however that you want to use a Bootstrap modal to accomplish this, you could define two separate functions to do something like:

```
function deleteIssuer(id){

  // This populates a hidden input field (you will need to create somewhere in the page) with the issuer ID
  $("#hiddenIdField").val(id);

  // Shows your modal
  $("#IssuerMappingDeleteModal").modal("show");

}

function sendDeleteRequest(){

  var id = $("#hiddenIdField").val(); // Pass this id to Ajax function

  /*** Ajax request to server to delete goes here ***/

}
```

Finally, you'll also need to replace the `<input type="submit" value="Yes" class="btn btn-danger" >` button on your modal with something like `<button type="button" onClick="sendDeleteRequest()" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>`

---

In both cases, you'll be calling the `deleteIssuer(id)` function from the Delete button you've created, so replace your `<a>` tag with: `<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right" onClick="deleteIssuer({{ issuer.Id }})">Delete</button>`

This should get you pretty close to what you need, you'll just need to define the `$.ajax()` request and server-side delete handler and you should be all set. It'd also be good to add some csrf protection if you can, to avoid certain types of exploits.

Comment: thanks for the extended answer, i will try that today and let you know

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find('#issMapId').html($('<b> Issuer Mapping id: ' + issuerMappingId  + '</b>'))
```

Your context of `this` is still the button... that's why it can't find `#issMapId`

Try `$(document).find('#issMapId').html($('<b> Issuer Mapping id: ' + issuerMappingId  + '</b>'))`

Comment: I would like to add that this is only a simple fix to your problem but I would suggest you take the suggestions of the other answer to produce more robust code.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i have tried a few more things (also went through a javascript tutorial, wished i had done that earlier). An answer by @therecluse26 (much appreciated for the thorough answer) suggested to use ajax (as opposed to a form) to send my delete request. However, as i am very new to this and I am not confident user yet I kept my solution with a form.

so i have updated my js function as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function deleteButtonClicked(issMapId, issMapName) {
            document.getElementById("issMapId").innerHTML = "Allocation Code " + issMapName + " (id:" + issMapId + ") will be deleted. <br>Do you want to proceed?";
            var element = document.getElementById("deleteForm");
            element.setAttribute("action",  "issuer-mappings/delete-issuer-mapping/" + issMapId)
        }
    </script>
```

and i have updated my modal code as below and it currently works.

```
<div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- display some how the id here-->
                    <p id="issMapId"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <form id="deleteForm" method="POST"> <!-- to add the delete action later -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                        <input type="submit" value="Yes" class="btn btn-danger" >
                    </form>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                </div>
```

and this is the button that shows the modal

```
<td>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right"
                       onclick="deleteButtonClicked({{ issuer.Id}},'{{ issuer.AllocationCode }}')"
                       data-toggle="modal" data-target="#IssuerMappingDeleteModal">Delete</a>
                </td>
```